# Does cabling between a mini-split indoor and outdoor unit need conduit?

Tags: electrical, hvac, air-conditioning, conduit, mini-split

I am installing a mini-split AC system where there are multiple indoor units connected to a single outdoor unit.  For each indoor unit, there is a separate 4-conductor cable that connects to the outdoor unit, and each cable is routed outside from a different location.

This is the condenser unit:
https://www.supplyhouse.com/LG-LMU24CHV-20000-BTU-Multi-F-Inverter-Heat-Pump-Outdoor-Unit

This is the cable I am using to connect the indoor units to the outdoor units:
https://www.genesis.resideo.com/all-products/comfort-hvac/mini-split/1070
-14/4 stranded, jacketed, rated for direct burial and sunlight resistant.  Type TC-ER-JP 600V

The outside condenser unit has a hole for attaching a conduit fitting for the indoor to outdoor cabling, but there is only one hole for multiple cable, from multiple sources.

Since the cabling I am using seems like it can be used for outdoor use, do I need to run the cables through a conduit, or can they be run as is?  Also, what is the best way to get multiple cables from multiple sources into the single hole in the condenser housing, and still ensure that the connection is waterproof?

Comment: A very good question.  My first knee-jerk would be no, as that cable looks, walks and quacks like *cordage*, but if they're selling it for that purpose, then maybe.

Comment: Ok, then if I need to use a conduit, what's the best way to put multiple cables in the same conduit opening when they are exiting from different locations on the house?  Should I just run the various cables through dedicated to a weatherproof junction box, then run all the cables together to the outdoor unit through another piece of conduit?

Comment: The spec sheet said type TC (tray cable) but only having 1 port is different than the multiple zone splits I have installed, on other brands the cable is allowed to be routed with the pressure and suction line , I did not have time to scan the entire guide but you may have the wrong cover or there are multiple knockouts you haven’t noticed. The MFG may be using article 727 as the requirements of the indoor unit are small. Ant ITC has a wide usage under 5 amps @150v or less the indoor units I have installed meet this requirement.

Comment: @EdBeal -- I think this is standard Chapter 3 TC not ITC/PLTC

Comment: How big is the hole in the condenser housing, and is the outdoor unit in an area where the cable route is susceptible to injury from mowers, weed whackers/string trimmers, and so on?

Comment: Three phase you are right I was racing through the info I could find and went two quick, it is different than what I have installed.+

Comment: EdBeal, You were right.  There are two holes for wire entry, but there are also four additional punch outs that I didn't notice at first.  ThreePhaseEel, The condenser housing is 13" x 34" x 26" (height).  It's not directly in the path of lawn equipment, but it's not that far out of the way.

Comment: Even if it's not **Required**, it still might be a **Very Good Idea.**